# Related to the default iOS Keyboard that comes out in Input Filed(available in UI System)

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-gui

I am working on an app for iOS Platform. i have a Input Field available in the new UI System , but every time the White Classic keyboard comes out to take input. I want to display the keyboard with a black semi-transparent background. Can anyone help me out with this?

I tried 
TouchScreenKeyboard.Open("", TouchScreenKeyboardType.Default, false, false, true, true); T
his opens the black semi-transparent background keyboard but when i hit the input field again then the classic white keyboard comes.

I want the black semi-transparent background keyboard as my default keyboard.

Thank You for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the answer to my own question.

Open your project in Xcode.
Open the Classes Folder.
Inside it open the UI Folder.
Inside it open the file Keyboard.mm

Classes>UI Folder>Keyboard.mm

[we can see the UIKeyboardAppearance selection]
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKr7n.png

In here we can see two type of keyboards

1.UIKeyboardAppearanceDefault

2.UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert

and below there is a line that decides which type of keyboard should appear

keyboardAppearances[alert ? 1 : 0],

Just change the order of the keyboard appearance according to your convenience

This is a cheap solution.
Actually you should change the value of the alert bool from wherever this method is being called

[see the UnityKeyboard_Show Method]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJNL6.png